# How can I get a ToC to show colored rectangles when clicked upon them?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, tocloft, links, hyperlink

## The situation

I've done a simple ToC:
[image]

When you click it, it redirects to the page, and shows a blue rectangle:[image]

## The issue

I don't know why this happens. I have currently two windows opened in `overleaf` with the same code for the ToC, same packages (they're the same project) and in one I get this blue colored ToC, which is desirable. But in the newer one this doesn't happen.

I've checked `hyperref` and other packages' documentation, but it says nothing about this.
Btw, the package `xurl` causes a `fatal error` in one project and loads without error in the other one.

The projects consist of same code, same packages… I suspect that the newer project got updated while the older one didn't update to the packages' new libraries, hence the differences. But maybe someone else knows more.

## My code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{comment} % Permite crear bloques de comentarios en el código
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\selectfont\sffamily} % USE PACKAGE sectsty
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{comment} 
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\selectfont\sffamily} % USE PACKAGE sectsty

\usepackage[breaklinks={true},
    runbordercolor=blue]{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks, % set true if you want colored links
    linktoc=all, % set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
    linkcolor=black, % choose some color if you want links to stand out
    citecolor=black,
    breaklinks=true,
    urlcolor=[RGB]{0,115,186}
}
```

Comment: Where do your two documents differ? Are their compiled versions both newer than their `*.tex` files? Did you try an offline `LaTeX` editor/compiler to exactly know what happens during compilation and that it's a `LaTeX` issue (just to be sure)? Could you provide a MWE ([minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example))?

Comment: The problem has solved itself. I did nothing. I guess this kind of thing happens when you're using cloud compilers.

Comment: Second edit: The problem dissapeared when I copied the project (made an exact copy of it in my main page in overleaf).